# How to overide Sku filter funtion

Tags: magento-2.3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUwHa.png)

How to overide Sku filter funtion and change comma seprate value for multi search

Answer (score 0):

In the native magento exits method `addAttributeToFilter` in product collection. you can use it in your case for ex:

```
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('sku', ['in' => ('EX-SKU-01','EX-SKU-02');
```